# Unable to get height from useRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to get the height of the div from my project. But when I run this I get `Property 'offsetHeight' does not exist on type 'never'`

This is my code:

```
const customMenuRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (customMenuRef) {
        console.log(customMenuRef.current?.offsetHeight);
    }
}, [customMenuRef]);

return (
    <div ref={customMenuRef}>
        test
    </div>
);
```

If I simply run `console.log(customMenuRef.Current)` I do get a current object with all the info I need, but I simply can't reach them.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or other reproducible example? I've pasted you code into a fresh create-next-app and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

```js
const customMenuRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (customMenuRef) {
        console.log(customMenuRef.current?.offsetHeight);
    }
}, [customMenuRef]);

return (
    <div ref={customMenuRef}>
        test
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Also, probably makes sense to check `customMenuRef.current`, since `customMenuRef` is an object and always will be truthy anyway. That also removes the need to use optional chaining in the inner logic.